# Complex SQL Joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have three tables which I'm needing to create a view from. The tables are (simplified):

network(**networkid**, name)

user(**userid**, *networkid*, name)

message(**messageid**, *userid*, recipient, message, timestamp)

Where **bold** are primary keys, and *italics* are foreign keys.

I'm needing a view, messages (**messageid**, network, recipient, user, message, timestamp).

Where network is network.name, recipient is message.recipient, user is user.name, message is message.message, and timestamp is message.timestamp

I'm pretty stuck currently. Creating a view starting from the message table gives me troubles trying to get the network_name, because it's two tables back. I know the user_id of the message, and from the user I can get the network.

What I have, and what is probably horribly wrong (and not complete) is:

`CREATE VIEW messages AS
SELECT  message.messageid, network.name, message.recipient, nick.nick, message.message, message.time
FROM    message
    JOIN nick ON nick.nick_id = message.nick_id`

I am using PostgreSQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use three `JOINS`:

```
CREATE VIEW messages AS
SELECT m.messageid, n.name, m.recipient, u.name, m.message, m.timestamp
FROM message m
    JOIN user u ON m.userid = u.userid
    JOIN network n ON u.networkid = n.networkid
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Awesome this did it! Much simpler than I was thinking it was going to be. Thanks.